# How to contribute binary .debs for others?

Tags: apt, deb, source, contributing

I routinely work with Armhf devices, however not all the packages I use exist in a form that apt-get can easily install. Therefore I spend a lot of time compiling from source packages that exist on x86 and amd64 repositories.

In order to save my time in the future and others time as well, is there a way that is approved to build binaries and then push them back to the repository for others to use?

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update 2:

PPAs on Launchpad can be used for distributing packages for the x86/amd64 architectures. Other architectures are usually only available for the core team. As @saiarcot says, ARMhf builds can be made available for public PPAs [on request](https://dev.launchpad.net/CommunityARMBuilds):

> You may request an ARM build on your PPA if
>
> - Your build takes 4hrs or less to build
> - You have less than 10 builds a week.
>
> To make this request please file an question on Launchpad and it will be dealt with. Note requests are dealt individually and Launchpad reserves discretion on the final say.

So the simplest way would be to set up a [private repository](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToSetupADebianRepository).

To get to the main repository is a bit more work. The Ubuntu Wiki article on [Contribute To Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ContributeToUbuntu#Contributing_to_the_Universe_Repository_.28MOTU.29) has a lot of detail about this. Essentially, you start of by uploading and maintaining something for the Universe repository and then once you have gained experience, apply for contributing to the Main repository.

---

This is what [PPAs](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA) are used for:

> Using a Personal Package Archive (PPA), you can distribute software and updates directly to Ubuntu users. Create your source package, upload it and Launchpad will build binaries and then host them in your own apt repository.

Comment: ARMhf builds can be requested in public PPAs provided they meet [these](https://dev.launchpad.net/CommunityARMBuilds) conditions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about saving specific debs for other machines for offline install use dpkg-repack but if you want an offline repo for your own use there are ways of doing that (though not an area of my expertise) and it takes up maybe a terabyte at most.